# Spring boot security | Why does my authenticationManager not work?

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, jwt

So I am making my first spring boot project (I am making a RESTful backend API) and I came across jwt authentication. After trying a few tutorials I was keep getting stuck until one tutorial kinda helped me.

**My problem:**

When I run my **AuthenticationController**:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class JwtAuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;


    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {

       try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword())
            );} catch (BadCredentialsException e){
            throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password", e);
        }


        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
                .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);


        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveUser(@RequestBody UserDTO user) throws Exception {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userDetailsService.save(user));
    }
}
```

My code does not run past this piece of code:

```
try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword())
            );} catch (BadCredentialsException e){
            throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password", e);
        }
```

I know this because of debugging basically. It always goes to the catch and I don't know why.
When I comment out that not working piece of code, my code runs but I can use any username and password with the given jwt Token, and that is not what I want.

So I know the piece of code that makes sure my program does not run as planned is that piece.

I know the not working piece of code uses my JwtRequest so maybe anyone needs that to help me fix my problem:

**JwtRequest:**

```
package com.example.demo.Model;

public class JwtRequest{

  

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public JwtRequest() {
    }

    public JwtRequest(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Here is my debugger and database to confirm that the credentials are correct:

**My debugger:**
[image: Debugger]

**My DataBase:**

[image: MY Database]

**My Postman:**

[image: Postman]

**What I have tried:**

I have tried replacing this code:

```
 try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword())
            );} catch (BadCredentialsException e){
            throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password", e);
        }
```

With this:

```
authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());
```

**And my according authenticate method:**

```
private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    try {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
    } catch (DisabledException e) {
        throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
        throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
    }
}
```

But then my debugger says this:
[image: Debuggger2]

I am basically stuck and I do not know what to do now. Can anyone help me or provide me with a tutorial on how to implement JWT authentication with an MYSQL database that is not outdated and has the source code included in the tutorial?
Thanks!
If you need some piece of code just ask and I will include it in the post.

**As requested the following files:**

**WebSecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {//provides security for endpoints

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    private final AccountService accountService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()//So we can send post requests without being rejected(if we using form based indication we want to enable this)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate","/register")
                .permitAll()//any request that goes trough that end point we want to allow.
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(accountService);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

**Password encoder:**

```
@Configuration
public class PasswordEncoder{

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }




}
```

**UserdetailsService:**

```
@Service
public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        DAOUser user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());

    }
    public DAOUser save(UserDTO user) {
        DAOUser newUser = new DAOUser();
        newUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        newUser.setPassword(bcryptEncoder.bCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
        return userDao.save(newUser);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also share you security configuration and `UserDetailsService`. If you want to take a different route, you can check out this [JWT login](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/master/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login) sample, although the architecture is different than what you're currently using.

Comment: Have provided `passwordEncoder` bean? Please show your security configuration

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana I added it

Comment: @ArfatBinkileb I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
@Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(accountService);
        return provider;
    }
```

You are setting `accountService` as `userDetailsService` instead of `JwtUserDetailsService'. have you tried that?

change in `JwtUserDetailsService.java`

```java
    //not sure why accountService-> don't make it final
    //@Autowired //missing
    //private AccountService accountService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;
```

```java
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
//@EnableWebSecurity not needed
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {//provides security for endpoints

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    //private AccountService accountService;
    @Autowired 
    private PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()//So we can send post requests without being rejected(if we using form based indication we want to enable this)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate","/register")
                .permitAll()//any request that goes trough that end point we want to allow.
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                //.and().addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); You are not using filter to authenticate, you are using a controller for that

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        //provider.setUserDetailsService(accountService);
        return provider;
    }
}
```